# how to print string that has " . " in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to print 23.45 and 7.8 by searching "." in each string.
here is my code.

```
mylist = ["1,23.45,6,7.8","1,25,999"]

tokens =mylist[0].split(',')

for number in tokens :

if re.search('.', number) :

print number ,
```

outcome: 1 23.45 6 7.8

Comment: Use `\.` rather than `.` and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

As always, I advise people not to use regex when they don't need regex.  In this case, use the `in` operator.

```
if '.' in number:
```

replaces

```
if re.search('.', number):
```

Which, if you're curious, should have been

```
if re.search('\.', number):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Regex doesn't look pythonic at all for me.

```
mylist = ["1,23.45,6,7.8","1,25,999"]
tokens =mylist[0].split(',')

for number in tokens :
    if "." in number:   
        print number
```

But my special favorite doesn't look much pythonic. But i learned to love lambdas over loops.

```
mylist = ["1,23.45,6,7.8","1,25,999"]
tokens =mylist[0].split(',')
result = filter(lambda x: "." in x, tokens)
print result
```

Comment: You need to indent that last line more.